# Using curl in a bash script, how do I effectively log into Google Voice?

Tags: bash, curl

My bash script is doing the following:

```
curl -k -s -c gv.cookies https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin -F Email=something@gmail.com -F Passwd=somepassword -F service=grandcentral
```

This seems to work. The cookies file is created, and if I peruse the output, it certainly thinks that I've logged in.

However, when I next do this:

```
curl -k -s -b gv.cookies https://www.google.com/voice/
```

I get a "moved temporarily" page, and not the Google Voice markup that I expect.

Am I missing some parameter to curl that makes it use the cookies correctly? I don't need it fixed so much as I need someone to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `-b` & `-L` flags :

```
curl \
    -L \
    -k \
    -s \
    -c gv.cookies \
    -b gv.cookies \
    -F Email=something@gmail.com \
    -F Passwd=somepassword \
    -F service=grandcentral \
    https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin
```

> -L, --location
>
> (HTTP/HTTPS)  If  the  server reports that the requested page has moved to a different location (indicated with a
>   Location: header and a 3XX response code), this option will make curl
>                  redo the request on the new place.

And

> -b, --cookie
>
> (HTTP)  Pass  the  data  to  the  HTTP  server  as  a  cookie. It is supposedly the data previously received from the server in a "Set-Cookie:" line.  The data should be in the format
>                  "NAME1=VALUE1; NAME2=VALUE2".

If it's not sufficient, try to change the [user-agent](/questions/tagged/user-agent) for the [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) one by example.